# Rewriting Tensorflow 1.x code to tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am dealing with a task where I have to create a code using TensorFlow-version2. I have an existing code of the same thing but in TensorFlow version 1.

```
with tf.variable_scope(name):
        self.obs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None] + list(ob_space.shape), name='obs')

        with tf.variable_scope('policy_net'):
            layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.obs, units=20, activation=tf.tanh)
            layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units=20, activation=tf.tanh)
            layer_3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_2, units=act_space.n, activation=tf.tanh)
            self.act_probs = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_3, units=act_space.n, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

I have worked on tf2 directly but I am facing challenges in understanding the given excerpt. Please help me understand it. Also, how can rewrite this code suitable for tf2. kindly suggest or provide me with a doc to do so.

For this, I will be really thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2:

1. [Manually migrate low level TensorFlow APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)
2. [Automatically upgrade code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade)

Comment: Please add context to the links. It is so because in case the links get deprecated the answer may become out of use. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. The automatic code conversion helped.

I have one more query. Can we completely remove with tf.variable_scope(name):

Comment: Can we use with tf.GradientTape() as tape: ?

Comment: Answer to both of your questions are it's depend on your code, I haven't had chance to migrate any code yet, you can try to remove one `with tf.variable_scope(name)`  or modify one `with tf.GradientTape() as tape:` see it work or not : )

Comment: @RajRajeshwariPrasad, If this answer helpful, then please make the question solved to let other know, have good day : )